# Kubernetes does not evict nodes despite limit being set

Tags: kubernetes

I changed the default eviction policy set by kops to include the condition `memory.available<1Gi`. The `--eviction-hard` flag is now set as:

`memory.available<1Gi,nodefs.available<10%,nodefs.inodesFree<5%,imagefs.available<10%,imagefs.inodesFree<5%`

The available memory on one node right now is at 400Mb and has been like this for quite a while. No pod eviction is happening.

Why isn't the kubelet evicting pods to make room? There's plenty of room on other nodes.

Is there an `AND` between eviction conditions? How can I see what the kubelet sees for memory usage?

Comment: try to run this [script](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/memory-available.sh), it reproduces the same set of steps that the `kubelet` performs to calculate `memory.available`

Comment: That script shows about 2 gigs of RAM free whereas htop shows about 800mb free. Is there some configuration related changes that I need to make to have kubectl read what htop is reading?

Comment: there is no such opportunity to change it in Kubernetes configuration. But it is not good idea to use htop in this case, because it counts memory with caches

Answer (score 0):

Your pods might have quality of service class set to Guaranteed, that's possible reason they are not getting evicted.

See:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/#qos-classes